# How to use ternary conditional on object in loop?

Tags: object, d3.js, key, ternary-operator

I'm new with D3.JS and I want to visualise some data in a graph. The data is stored in an object. I want to make a graph with day & night temperatures. It's stored in the object as below:

```
{
"datum": "2016-09-11",
"day": "22",
"night": "16"
},
```

I've used a ternary condition to shift between 'day' and 'night' every time it loops and saved the value in a variable (key) so I can use it to get the key value from the data object. But somehow it doesn't work .. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here? I hope my problem is clear .. Here the full code:

```
var i;

var barOffset = 10;
var barSpacing = 20;

d3.json('weather.json', function (data) {
    console.table(data);

  for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

    var key = i % 2 === 0 ? 'night' : 'day';

    console.log(data.length);

      d3.select('svg')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', barOffset * (i *2))
      .attr('y', 400 - 4*data[i][key])
      .attr('width', barSpacing)
      .attr('height', 4*data[i][key])
      .attr('class', i % 2 === 0 ? 'night' : 'day');

  }
});
```

I hope someone can help me! Thanks! :)

Comment: You can achieve the same thing using `.enter(data)` and supplying functions to attr which take the index and data

Comment: If you could explain a bit more what "doesn't work", that could help :)

Comment: @Benjamin The graph only shows the temperature of 4 days (day & night), but it's supposed to show 7 days. After 8 loops it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'night' of undefined - I think it is something with the 'data[i][key]' that goes wrong

Comment: That's right, the error is not with the ternary condition. It's to do with your `data[i]` not existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 provides its own way to negate (pretty much) the need for "for" loops, which is the `selection.data(data).enter()` pattern, which allows you to use functions to determine svg elements' properties and attributes.

Before the `d3.json` call define your `svg` element:

```
var svg=d3.select('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',500);
```

Then instead of using a for loop you can do something like, inside your `d3.json` call:

```
//once for the day

svg.selectAll('rect.day').data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d,i) {return barOffset * (i * 4);})
.attr('y', function(d,i) {return 400 - 4*d.day;})
.attr('width', barSpacing)
.attr('height', function(d,i) {return 4*d.day;})
.attr('class', "day");

//again for the night...

svg.selectAll('rect.night').data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d,i) {return barOffset * (i * 4 + 2);})
.attr('y', function(d,i) {return 400 - 4*d.night;})
.attr('width', barSpacing)
.attr('height', function(d,i) {return 4*d.night;})
.attr('class', "night");
```

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/luleze/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have 7 days worth of data, but are looping on 14 days. So after 7 days, `data[i]` is undefined, hence the error.

Try with:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  ["night", "day"].forEach(function(key) {
    d3.select('svg')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', barOffset * (i *2))
      .attr('y', 400 - 4*data[i][key])
      .attr('width', barSpacing)
      .attr('height', 4*data[i][key])
      .attr('class', key);
  });
}
```